# v(1, 0, 0) -> v(0, -1, 0) with rotation matrix?

Tags: matrices

How can v(1, 0, 0) be changed to v(0, -1, 0) with a single rotation matrix?

I suppose a 2D vector of v(1, 0) -> v (0, -1) is fine as well.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! It really helps to format questions using MathJax (see FAQ). Regards

Answer (score 0):

$\left(\begin{smallmatrix} 0&1\\ -1&0 \end{smallmatrix}\right)$

Comment: Why am I getting different answers from everyone?

Comment: Just multiply out the matrix against the vector to see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

In the 3D example you're looking for a 90 degree rotation around the Z axis (direction depends on the orientation of your axis). I don't remember how to construct 3D rotation matrices.

In your 2D example, you just want a 90 degree rotation clockwise around the origin, which is much easier:

```
[ cos 90, -sin 90
  sin 90,  cos 90 ]
```

which is

```
[ 0, -1
  1,  0 ]
```

Comment: Why am I getting different answers from everyone?

Comment: @DraKE45 on a 2D plane we assume a Z axis in a particular direction. However, in 3D the Z axis can point in the other direction if that's how your coordinate system is defined, which would mean the rotation is in the opposite direction. user66345 chose that other coordinate system, so his answer is the inverse of mine.

Comment: Does yours assume a left or right coordinate system?

Comment: @DraKE45 I think mine is for left handed coordinate systems and his is for right.